# Powershell script to compare csv rows

Tags: powershell, csv, compare, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I have two csv files with following columns

**Csv1**

```
Name| address| phone 
John| Blah | Blah 
Dave| Blah | Blah 
Rick| Blah | Blah
```

**Csv2**

```
Name |address| phone 
John| Blah| Blah 
Dave| Blah| Blah
```

***I want unique rows from first csv***

What i want

```
Name | address| phone 
Rick | Blah   | Blah
```

My code

```
$csv1 = import-csv <file> $csv2 = import-csv <file>
$output = $csv1 | where-object {$_.name -notin $csv2.Name -and $_.address -notin $csv2.address -and $_.phone -notin $csv2.phone}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your statement**
 `| where-object {$_.name -notin $csv2.Name -and $_.address -notin $csv2.address -and $_.phone -notin $csv2.phone}`

**The logic when evaluating Rick's row**

- Is Rick a name that is in `$Csv2` ? (Answer:No)
- Is Blah an address in `$Csv2` ? (Answer: Yes)
- Is Blah a phone number in `$Csv2` ? (Answer: Yes)

You are evaluating every single row against all of the rows of `$csv2` so when you check Rick's address (`$_.address -notin $csv2.address`), it is actually in `$Csv2` for John and Dave. Based on how you formulated your condition, that does eliminate Rick from the unique rows.

You can use Compare-Object to compare both csv files and find items that aren't a match. Here is a demonstration comparing both csv using the 3 properties as criterias.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csv1 -DifferenceObject $csv2 -Property Name,Address,phone  | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='
```

**Complete self-contained example**

```
$Csv1 = @'
Name|address|phone
John|Blah|Blah
Dave|Blah|Blah
Rick|Blah|Blah
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'


$csv2 = @'
Name|address|phone
John|Blah|Blah
Dave|Blah|Blah
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'


$Results = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csv1 -DifferenceObject $csv2 -Property Name,Address,phone  | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='

$Results | Select Name,Address,Phone
```

**Output**

```
Name Address phone
---- ------- -----
Rick Blah    Blah
```